# Using AutoFac Property Injection with Moq

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, automoq

Consider the following class:

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public IService Service { get; protected set; }
}
```

and this test for the class:

```
using var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose();
var viewModelBase = mock.Create<ViewModelBase>();
Assert.NotNull(viewModelBase.Service);
```

In my normal application, I'm using the property injection functionality of `Autofac.Core.NonPublicProperty` to autowire the `IService` dependency into the `ViewModelBase`:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType(typeof(ViewModelBase)).AutoWireNonPublicProperties();
```

In the test, I'm using the `Autofac.Extras.Moq` integration package to automatically mock dependencies for `ViewModelBase`. However, as far as I can tell, only constructor injection is supported by `Autofac.Extras.Moq`. This causes the test to fail because the `Service` property is not autowired by Moq.

Is there any elegant way of utilizing the property injection function of AutoFac with Moq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> only constructor injection is supported by Autofac.Extras.Moq

Actually you are right, but the `AutoMock.GetLoose` has an overload in which you can inject to the mock a fully functioned `IContainer` by passing a delegate of `ContainerBuilder` with all the regular *autofac* features:

```
public class AutoMock : IDisposable
{
    //...  
    public IContainer Container { get; }
    public static AutoMock GetLoose(Action<ContainerBuilder> beforeBuild);
    //...
}
```

In your case the extension `Autofac.Extras.Moq` is not supporting the `PropertiesAutowired()` method so we can build a ContainerBuilder and pass it with a delegate:

```
Action<ContainerBuilder> containerBuilderAction = delegate(ContainerBuilder cb)
{
    cb.RegisterType<ServiceFoo>().As<IService>();
    cb.RegisterType<ViewModelBase>().PropertiesAutowired(); //The autofac will go to every single property and try to resolve it.
};

var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose(containerBuilderAction);
        
var viewModelBase = mock.Create<ViewModelBase>();            
Assert.IsNotNull(viewModelBase.Service);
```

With `IService` implementation class of `ServiceFoo`:

```
public class ServiceFoo : IService` { }
```